# how to Remove available quantity validation?

Tags: cart, addtocart, qty-increment

We tried to remove the available quantity validation on "add to cart" and changed the setting "decreasing qty" is No. 
Our Client request to remove the quantity validation while addto cart. They produce the product while order from customer. So they dont want available quantity validation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a running instance of Magento right now (since I am setting up a new computer) so I can't give you the exact location, but you should be able to turn something like `Manage Stock` off under orders in `System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Inventory -> Product Stock Options`. This should completely disable the inventory function as well as all quantity validation.

Answer (score 0):

Not system - it's Store

Store -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Inventory -> Product Stock Options